# Would I be able to install Brave and Proton Mail on GrapheneOS?

Tags: applications, custom-roms, installation

I'm thinking about picking up a Google Pixel 4 and installing GrapheneOS.

Would I be able to install apps like ProtonMail and Brave somehow?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that you won't be? GrapheneOS does allow users to install apps from third-party repositories which in simple words means that it does allow installing apps from unknown sources. https://grapheneos.org/faq#bundled-apps

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already found the answer in the last two and a half years, but yes you can install any android apps on GrapheneOS. You could always side-load any app or install from sources like fdroid or the aurora store, but now you can also install the [Sandboxed Google Play Services](https://grapheneos.org/usage#sandboxed-google-play) and use the play store as you would on stock android.